# Ajax.BeginForm in VS 2015 ASP.NET vNext missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I read about @Html.BeginForm and also @Ajax.BeginForm in an earlier release of ASP.NET MVC for Razor Views. Then I opened VS 2015 to try both forms with ASP.NET vNext but I can't find the Ajax object. Am I missing something? Do I have to include some extra Nuget package? Is there some new way to use Ajax.BeginForm? Hasn't it been added yet to VS 2015 (MVC 6)? Was it removed? Or what?

Note: I'm not interested in pure HTML/JavaScript alternatives.

Comment: It hasn't yet been implemented, and I'm not entirely sure if it will be. The "AJAX Helpers" were fairly limited in functionality, and most developers seemed to have gone directly to solutions involving Angular, Knockout, and similar JavaScript/AJAX libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, makes sense! Let's wait until final release. I am new to web programming but some kind of Ajax is a must.

Comment: TagHelper could be a replacement for the "AJAX Helpers"? You can specify a "controller" and a "action" attribute in a <form> tag. It will automatically render the correct "action" attribute. Don't know if it also works for AJAX actions.

Answer (score 3):

jquery ajax unobtrusive is open source (https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive) and can be pulled through bower.

After importing it you can use it's data attributes to the same behaviour as Ajax.BeginForm.

`+------------------------+-------------------------------+
|      AjaxOptions       |        HTML attribute         |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Confirm                | data-ajax-confirm             |
| HttpMethod             | data-ajax-method              |
| InsertionMode          | data-ajax-mode                |
| LoadingElementDuration | data-ajax-loading-duration    |
| LoadingElementId       | data-ajax-loading             |
| OnBegin                | data-ajax-begin               |
| OnComplete             | data-ajax-complete            |
| OnFailure              | data-ajax-failure             |
| OnSuccess              | data-ajax-success             |
| UpdateTargetId         | data-ajax-update              |
| Url                    | data-ajax-url                 |
+------------------------+-------------------------------+`

Answer (score 0):

MVC 6 makes use of Tag Helpers as an alternative to HTML Helper.
[This post](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc-6-form-tag-helper.aspx) by Dave Paquette on his blog explains about Form Tag Helpers
In [this post](http://www.trycatchexfinally.co.uk/posts/tag-helpers-mvc-6-vnext) the chap has created his own Ajax Form Tag Helper

I don't think you can just add `@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax` into your `_ViewImports.cshtml`.
The `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` library makes use of jQuery, so it might be better creating your own solution using the above links - This will give you more control and access of promises as well